# For loop function with two subscripts

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am new to writing loop functions and I am trying to solve this. I would like the `y` matrix to be populated with the values obtained from the `for` loop. Unfortunately y remains blank and full of 0's after the loop is executed.

```
mv <- c(0,1,2)  # location vector
s <- 1          # scale
increment <- seq(-6,6,0.01)             # Create a sequence of x values
y=matrix(0,length(increment),length(mv))

for (i in length(increment)) {
        for (j in length(mv)) {
                y[i,j] <- 1/(1+ exp(-(increment[i]-mv[j])/s))
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your loop to start at 1, for now it is only using 1 value (`length(increment)`):

```
for (i in 1:length(increment)) {
        for (j in 1:length(mv)) {
                y[i,j] <- 1/(1+ exp(-(increment[i]-mv[j])/s))
        }
}
```

Comment: Another option would be `y1 <- outer(seq_along(increment), seq_along(mv), FUN=Vectorize(function(i,j) 1/(1+exp(-(increment[i]- mv[j])/s))))`